# Postgres Date and Time formats

Tags: postgresql

What is the data-type for this date type in the postgres?

2020-01-04T16:25:25.000+05:30

if I use with date-time  with time zone it will only store
2020-01-04T16:25:25

Can i get some update on this?

Comment: This is timestamp with timezone. so use `timestampz` to store in database. You can refer this for better understanding [Click Here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp)

Comment: Yes.. but I'm not getting that option..

Comment: Just use it as the column's type, e.g. `create table t (the_column timestamptz)`;

Comment: See the [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Vyg9QTX2vTpAWwVjA58CH/2)

Comment: I'm able add, time with time zone in the postgres default/local db.. but in the server still getting the same problem.. In the both sides I'm using the query.. (CREATE TABLE public.example4
(
    date1 timestamptz,
    date2 timestamptz
))

Comment: Is the problem that you do not see the milliseconds (`000`) part of the `timestamptz`?  If so, then that is simply a formatting problem.    https://stackoverflow.com/a/62938325/13808319  If your problem is that you are not seeing the TZ part of the value, then that is probably because you, your server, or both are in the IST time zone.

Comment: Please show the actual actions/queries you are using to get the values you are reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue once. What I understood at that time, PostgreSQL is defaulted to UTC. Thats why you will always see +00, and not +5.30. To see that, first you have to set the data type as `timestamptz ( time stamp with time zone )` , second - you have to set the timeZone.  like `SET TIMEZONE='Asia/Kolkata'` , something like that.

or else, even though you do:

```
select TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02' AT TIME ZONE 'IST';
```

you will get to see only up to 54.

Comment: To be clear the ```timestamptz```  type is UTC.  ```timestamp``` is not.  Also you don't have to ```SET TIMEZONE```, Postgres will pick up the one set for your server. Especially in this case as the timestamp has the offset  present and setting the ```TIMEZONE``` is redundant.